# How to instantiate xamarin android/ios native custom control class in xamarin forms xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms

**Custom control class:**

```
public class CustomTextInput : UITextField
    {

    }
```

**Xamarin.Forms xaml:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:SampleApp.CustomControls;assembly=SampleApp"
             x:Name="SampleAppView">
<ContentPage.Content>            
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Sample_ic.png" WidthRequest="29" HeightRequest="29"/>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="Sample Text" TextColor="#717073" FontSize="Small" FontFamily="Helvetica"/>

            <!--Accessing IOS Custom control class-->
            <Custom:CustomTextInput Text="50 Gal"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="#838288" />
        </StackLayout>  
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Can I access android/IOS custom control class in xamarin.forms xaml? For sample I used *UITextField* control. But I need to access android/IOS platform specific custom controls which is not available in xamarin.forms.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms will render its control such as `Entry` into native controls for each specific platform, so what is your problem? Maybe you are looking for smth like Custome Renderers in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: No. I need to render android/ios specific controls which is not available in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: I think that you don't understand the Xamarin.Forms concept, please read about how it works and why you shouldn't take care about native controls in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xamarin.Forms, you're working with the platform independent controls. `UITextField` doesn't exist, but is instead mapped to an `Entry`.

Your best bet is to make a custom Entry subclass:

```
public class MyEntry : Entry
{
}
```

And use it in your XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="MyApp.SomePage"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp">
    <local:MyEntry />
</ContentPage>
```

Then, on each platform, you can provide a platform specific [Renderer](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/).

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(MyApp.MyEntry), typeof(MyApp.iOS.MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (null == Control)
                return;

            var textField = Control as UITextField;

            // do stuff with textField
        }
    }
}
```

If you find that rendering the custom controls individually does not provide the exact level of control you need, you can also make custom `Page` `Renderers`, as seen [here](http://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-uiviewcontrollers-in-xamarin.forms-on-ios/).